# Citation does not appear neither in TexStudio nor in TexMaker

Tags: citing

**Hello Everybody,**

I am working on a paper, aiming to submit it to Transportation Science journal, and I am using their template. I have difficult in citing the papers. The citations do not appear and I m using TexStudio and TexMaker.

My problems:

1) Why citations do not appear in the tex neither in the text body nor in the references.

2) there is some coding in the preamble for the citations, and I wonder if I need to modify my .bib file to follow the codes ( I mean the order of the title and author, year , etc.)

MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Author template for Transportation Science (trsc)
%% Mirko Janc, Ph.D., INFORMS, mirko.janc@informs.org
%% ver. 0.95, December 2010
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass[trsc,blindrev]{informs3}
\documentclass[trsc,nonblindrev]{informs3} % current default for manuscript submission

\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI % current default line spacing
%%\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII
%%\DoubleSpacedXII
%%\DoubleSpacedXI

% If hyperref is used, dvi-to-ps driver of choice must be declared as
%   an additional option to the \documentclass. For example
%\documentclass[dvips,trsc]{informs3}      % if dvips is used
%\documentclass[dvipsone,trsc]{informs3}   % if dvipsone is used, etc.

% Private macros here (check that there is no clash with the style)

% Natbib setup for author-year style
\usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%


%% Setup of theorem styles. Outcomment only one. 
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     % Preferred (Theorem 1, Lemma 1, Theorem 2)
%\TheoremsNumberedByChapter  % (Theorem 1.1, Lema 1.1, Theorem 1.2)

%% Setup of the equation numbering system. Outcomment only one.
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\EquationsNumberedThrough    % Default: (1), (2), ...
%\EquationsNumberedBySection % (1.1), (1.2), ...

% In the reviewing and copyediting stage enter the manuscript number.
%\MANUSCRIPTNO{} % When the article is logged in and DOI assigned to it,
                 %   this manuscript number is no longer necessary

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Outcomment only when entries are known. Otherwise leave as is and 
%   default values will be used.
%\setcounter{page}{1}
%\VOLUME{00}%
%\NO{0}%
%\MONTH{Xxxxx}% (month or a similar seasonal id)
%\YEAR{0000}% e.g., 2005
%\FIRSTPAGE{000}%
%\LASTPAGE{000}%
%\SHORTYEAR{00}% shortened year (two-digit)
%\ISSUE{0000} %
%\LONGFIRSTPAGE{0001} %
%\DOI{10.1287/xxxx.0000.0000}%

% Author's names for the running heads
% Sample depending on the number of authors;
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones and Wilson}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones, Miller, and Wilson}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones et al.} % for four or more authors
% Enter authors following the given pattern:
%\RUNAUTHOR{}

% Title or shortened title suitable for running heads. Sample:
% \RUNTITLE{Bundling Information Goods of Decreasing Value}
% Enter the (shortened) title:
%\RUNTITLE{}

% Full title. Sample:
% \TITLE{Bundling Information Goods of Decreasing Value}
% Enter the full title:
%\TITLE{}

% Block of authors and their affiliations starts here:
% NOTE: Authors with same affiliation, if the order of authors allows, 
%   should be entered in ONE field, separated by a comma. 
%   \EMAIL field can be repeated if more than one author
\ARTICLEAUTHORS{%
\AUTHOR{Author1}
\AFF{Author1 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}
\AUTHOR{Author2}
\AFF{Author2 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}
% Enter all authors
} % end of the block

\ABSTRACT{%
Text of your abstract % Enter your abstract
}%

% Sample
%\KEYWORDS{deterministic inventory theory; infinite linear programming duality; 
%  existence of optimal policies; semi-Markov decision process; cyclic schedule}

% Fill in data. If unknown, outcomment the field
\KEYWORDS{}
\HISTORY{}

\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Samples of sectioning (and labeling) in TRSC
% NOTE: (1) \section and \subsection do NOT end with a period
%       (2) \subsubsection and lower need end punctuation
%       (3) capitalization is as shown (title style).
%
%\section{Introduction.}\label{intro} %%1.
%\subsection{Duality and the Classical EOQ Problem.}\label{class-EOQ} %% 1.1.
%\subsection{Outline.}\label{outline1} %% 1.2.
%\subsubsection{Cyclic Schedules for the General Deterministic SMDP.}
%  \label{cyclic-schedules} %% 1.2.1
%\section{Problem Description.}\label{problemdescription} %% 2.

% Text of your paper here

\section{Introduction} \label{intro}
I wonder if you might know why this citation \citep{assad1980modelling} does not appear here.


% Acknowledgments here
\ACKNOWLEDGMENT{%
% Enter the text of acknowledgments here
}% Leave this (end of acknowledgment)


% Appendix here
% Options are (1) APPENDIX (with or without general title) or 
%             (2) APPENDICES (if it has more than one unrelated sections)
% Outcomment the appropriate case if necessary
%
% \begin{APPENDIX}{<Title of the Appendix>}
% \end{APPENDIX}
%
%   or 
%
% \begin{APPENDICES}
% \section{<Title of Section A>}
% \section{<Title of Section B>}
% etc
% \end{APPENDICES}


% References here (outcomment the appropriate case) 

% CASE 1: BiBTeX used to constantly update the references 
%   (while the paper is being written).
%\bibliographystyle{ormsv080} % outcomment this and next line in Case 1
%\bibliography{<your bib file(s)>} % if more than one, comma separated
\bibliographystyle{ormsv080}  
\bibliography{PaperRef} 

% CASE 2: BiBTeX used to generate mypaper.bbl (to be further fine tuned)
%\input{mypaper.bbl} % outcomment this line in Case 2

\end{document}
```

---

and the cited paper in my .bib file:

```
@article{assad1980modelling,
    title={Modelling of rail networks: toward a routing/makeup model},
    author={Assad, A.A.},
    journal={Transportation Research Part B: Methodological},
    volume={14},
    number={1},
    pages={101--114},
    year={1980},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

I would appreciate if you would have some solution to my problem.

**Regards
Bornay**

Comment: Do you run `bibtex`? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number for a description of how this works.

Comment: This is actually the error I get as I run BibTex:

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: trscTemplate.aux I couldn't open style file ormsv080.bst ---line 3 of file trscTemplate.aux : \bibstyle{ormsv080 : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 4 of file trscTemplate.aux : \bibstyle : {PaperRef} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no \bibdata command---while reading file trscTemplate.aux I found no style file---while reading file trscTemplate.aux (There were 4 error messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the line

```
\bibliographystyle{PaperRef}
```

to this:

```
\bibliography{PaperRef}
```

Assuming that "PaperRef.bib" is the name of your bibliograpy file.

(Currently, you do not have a literature file included in your document.)

Comment: Hi Tom, I appreciate your comment, but that was a typo, it is actually 
\bibliography{PaperRef}

and I have PaperRef.bib file in the same folder where the .tex file is saved.
It does not really work.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have the file ormsv080.bst somewhere where BibTeX can find it (e.g. in the same folder)?
If not, you need to retrieve a copy of that file. Propably the one from the journal itself.

However, you can try and download this [ormsv080.bst file](https://github.com/davidlove/lrlp_paper/blob/master/ormsv080.bst).

Comment: Hi Tom, I do not have .bst file in the document. But in the instruction, it says after the first run, trscTemplate.bib file will be generated.  and I have trscTemplate.bib file. But, it still fails to show the citation. The error says that the citation is undefined. I do not know how to download the ormsv.080.bst file. The link you shared has some coding, but not a file. t

Comment: Hi Tom, You were right. I could find the .bst file, and now it works fine. I appreciate it, thanks.